# Is it possible to eliminate $q$ from $\gcd\left(a (e-gq),(q^2-d)g-(e-gq)(q-p)\right)$?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Is it possible to eliminate the variable $q$ from the following gcd expression?
$$\gcd\left(a (e-gq),(q^2-d)g+(e-gq)(q-p)\right)$$

What I tried was the following:

Assuming that the gcd is $m$, I get
$$\frac{a(e-gq)}{n_1}=m \tag1$$
and so $$q=\frac{ae-mn_1}{a g} \tag2$$
for some integer $n_1$.
Now
$$\frac{(q^2-d)g+(e-gq)(q-p)}{n_2}=m \tag3$$
for some integer $n_2$. Substituting for $q$ from $(2)$, I have
$$a (e^2-d g^2)=m(n_2 a g+n_1 (e+g p)) \tag4$$
Therefore I conclude
$$\gcd\big(a (e-gq),(q^2-d)g+(e-gq)(q-p)\big)=\gcd\big(a (e-gq),a(e^2-d g^2)\big) \tag5$$

But this seems to be wrong. A simple substitution of $e1=4,g1=1,a=-3,d=17,q=5, p=4$ shows there is something not correct.

Can someone please point me where I am going astray? What then is the correct simplification?

Thanks.

Comment: Which value do you choose for $p$ in your counterexample? Did you test it line by line to detect the mistake? What are the details leading to $(4)?$

Comment: Ah sorry.. forgot $p$.. now edited to include it. I do not understand your question regarding details leading to $(4)$.. It is a simple substitution from $(2)$. Could you please clarify?

Comment: The claim in $(5)$ is clearly incorrect since that RHS gcd is divsiible by $\,a\,$ but the original gcd need not be. Generally if $(a,b)=1$ then $\,(b-aq,a^2)=1\,$ so $\, d := (b-aq,\,c_2 q^2+c_1 q+ c_0) = (b-aq, a^2(c_2 q^2+c_1 q+ c_0)) = (b-aq,\, c_2b^2 +  c_1 b a + c_0 a^2 )\,$ since $\,aq\equiv b\pmod{b-aq}\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I do not understand what you mean at all. What are $q$ and $d$ in your explanation? Can you please correct the answer? Also the gcds are missing.

Comment: As I wrote, $d$ is defined to be the gcd I compute, and $q$ is any integer. My notation does not connect to yours except for $\,q.\,$ The notation $(x,y) := \gcd(x,y)\,$ is standard in number theory.

Comment: Could *you* please double check and clarify how your substitution from $(2)$ leads to $(4)$? I find a different litteral and numerical result. I also doubt your $(4)\implies(5)$ (see Bill's objection).

Comment: @AnneBauval Oops.. you are right indeed.. There was a sign error in (3) that I have corrected and so everything that follows is now okay. Regarding the objection, I do not understand why it is so. Maybe could you or someone else please explain it? Thank you.

Comment: Bill already pointed the fact that $a$ divides the RHS of $(5)$ but generally not the LHS (why should it?). Your mistake was the following. Let $A=a(e-gq),B=(q^2-d)g+(e-gq)(q-p),m=\gcd(A,B),C=a(e^2-dg^2).$ You proved that $m$ divides $C,$ but this does not imply $m=\gcd(A,C).$

Comment: @AnneBauval I see.. But then is there a simplification of that gcd? Or this is the final reduced form?

Comment: There is no simplification.